# Could not load potsdamer_platz_1k.hdr: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, three.js, tailwind-css, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am currently working on building a Three.js customization t-shirt website, and I have encountered a persistent error when running the project. I am also experiencing the same error when trying to run the project live. I have included the file "platz_1k.hdr" in my public folder, but the issue persists, and I am unsure how to resolve it

I have attempted to update the "drei" package and have also included the necessary file, "platz_1k.hdr," but the error still persists. My goal is to resolve this error and ensure that my 3D model is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

faced the same problem for quite some time. Recently checked several methods to rectify it and then found this thread on GitHub, link: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/1492

So the most suggested solution was to upgrade the react-three/drei package to the above version 9.70.4

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the hdr file by  yourself?

Comment: no i didnt create